# jquery multiple checkboxes with modal

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I can't find an answer to this, and i don't really know how to do this. I have an html form with multiple checkboxes and a model. A minimum to send the form with the Submit button is one checkbox. The jquery script needs to iterate through all checkboxes and see if one or more is selected. If none is selected the bootstrap modal should appear as a warning message, and the form should not be send.

The html is as follows:

```
<form name="account_creation" method="post" action="" novalidate="novalidate" role="form">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="account_creation_roles">
                <div class="checkbox"><label for="account_creation_roles_1">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="account_creation_roles_1" name="account_creation[roles][]"
                               value="1" checked="checked">USER_ADMIN</label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox"><label for="account_creation_roles_2">
                        <input type="checkbox"
                               id="account_creation_roles_2"
                               name="account_creation[roles][]"
                               value="2" checked="checked">
                        USER</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="button-submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-warning" type="submit">Submit</button>
<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="display: none;" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The jquery code i have so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var $form = $('form[name="account_creation"]');

$form.on('submit', function(e) {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function() {
        if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').not(':checked').length == 0) {
            $(this).parents('form').submit();
        } else {
            $('#modal').show();
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

The checkboxes are generated so they will be with id `account_creation_roles_1`, `account_creation_roles_2` etc. I want to target `account_creation_roles` div and all the checkboxes in it. 
Thanks.

Comment: It's got an id so `$('#account_creation_roles')` would get the div and `$('#account_creation_roles').find(':checkbox:checked').length` would get the number of checkboxes checked.  If that is greater than 0, do your submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to iterate over all of the checkboxes.
You can select all unchecked (or checked) boxes and test the `length` of the selection.

Below, I'm checking for boxes that *are* checked.
If the length is greater than zero, then there's at least one box checked and the form is submitted.
Otherwise, the modal is shown.

```js
$(function() {

  var $form = $('form[name="account_creation"]');
  var $acctCreationRoles = $('#account_creation_roles');

  $form.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var atLeastOneChecked = $(':checkbox:checked', $acctCreationRoles).length > 0;
    if (atLeastOneChecked) {
      //$form.submit();
      console.log('submit');
    } else {
      //$('#modal').show();
      console.log('modal');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="account_creation" method="post" action="">
  <div id="account_creation_roles">
    <div><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> USER_ADMIN</div>
    <div><input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> USER</div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also see:
[`:checkbox` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)
[`:checked` selector](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)
[selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) or [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)